# How to display a Rails flash notice upon redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-flash

I have the following code in a Rails controller:

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Successfully checked in'
redirect_to check_in_path
```

Then in the /check_in view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

However, the notice does not show up. Works perfect if I don't redirect in the controller:

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Successfully checked in'
render action: 'check_in'
```

I need a redirect though... not just a rendering of that action. Can I have a flash notice after redirecting?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Remove the `.now`. So just write:

```
flash[:notice] = 'Successfully checked in'
redirect_to check_in_path
```

The `.now` is specifically supposed to be used when you are just rendering and not redirecting. When redirecting, the `.now` is not to be used.

Comment: Perfect! thanks. It's making me wait 6 more minutes to accept the answer for some reason...

Answer (score 45):

```
redirect_to new_user_session_path, alert: "Invalid email or password"
```

in place of `:alert` you can use `:notice`

to display

Answer (score 23):

Or you can do it in one line.

```
redirect_to check_in_path, flash: {notice: "Successfully checked in"}
```

Comment: @JayEl-Kaake what ruby version are you using?

Comment: It was a while ago, so I'm not sure... I'll redact my comment since it looks like that should work.

Comment: path, flash: {notice: ... seems like Rails 3, while path, alert: ... is Rails 4+

Comment: Nice solution, as it also allows different types of messages, e.g. flash: {success: "text"}

Answer (score 13):

This will work too

`redirect_to check_in_path, notice: 'Successfully checked in'`

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Bootstrap, this will display a nicely-formatted flash message on the page that's the target of your redirect.

In your controller:

```
if my_success_condition
  flash[:success] = 'It worked!'
else
  flash[:warning] = 'Something went wrong.'
end
redirect_to myroute_path
```

In your view:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

This will produce HTML like:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">It worked!</div>
```

For available Bootstrap alert styles, see: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/

Reference: https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/how-to-add-a-flash-message-to-your-rails-page/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and your question solved mine, because I had forgotten to include in the /check_in view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

In the controller, just a single line:

```
redirect_to check_in_path, :notice => "Successfully checked in"
```

Comment: yours is a different problem. I had the `<%= notice %>` tag, just nothing was coming up